# Tailwind theme config from my React components library not picked up by main app's Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, configuration, shared-libraries, tailwind-css

I have a React components library and a NextJS app. They both use TailwindCSS.

The app uses components from the library and renders the components well, except for the theme configurations from **tailwind.config.js** file of the library.

I'm using Nx monorepo, in case that has a thing to play here, but I highly doubt it.

What am I missing?

App's next.config.js:

```js
//@ts-check

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { withNx } = require('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx');

/**
 * @type {import('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/
const nextConfig = {
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: true,
  }
};

module.exports = withNx(nextConfig);
```

App's tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js'
  ],
  content: [
    'apps/ac-dcp/**/*.{html,js,jsx,tsx,ts}',
    'libs/moonlight-neon-ui/src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,tsx,ts}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Lib's tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    'libs/moonlight-neon-ui/src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,tsx,ts}'
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      jost: ['Jost', 'Poppins', 'Verdana', 'sans-serif'],
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'background': '#141414',

        'hlt': '#5f5f5f9e',
        'hlb': '#121212',
        'bgt': '#202227',
        'bgb': '#3b3d43',
        'bght': '#2a2c33',
        'bghb': '#43464d',
        
        'cbg': '#1c1e23',
        'cbgb': '#24262a',

        'glow': '#fbb615bf',

        'p1': '#f26e25',
        'p1h': '#f26e259C',
        'p2': '#fbb615',
        'p2h': '#fbb6159C',
        'pb': '#1a1a1a',
        'pw': '#f3f3f3',

        's1': '#ef3e23',
        's2': '#f37b21',
        'sb': '#231f20',
        'sw': '#fff',

        // 979797 > 500
        // 262626 > 900
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets), you need to `require()` the preset file into the consumer `tailwind.config.js`, such that the preset has the configuration object value:

```js
presets: [
  require('libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js'),
],
```

Please note, you might need to adjust the path passed to the `require()`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I've got another question, is this "presets" even really needed to make this work?

Comment: Yep! I'd say so.

Comment: Any idea what i could try changing the path to, as adding require() to this produces Error: Cannot find module 'libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js'

libs is located in the home directory of the workspace

Comment: You may need to use a path relative to the app's `tailwind.config.js`. For example, if it is located at `/my/computer/path/app/tailwind.config.js` and `libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js` is at `/my/computer/path/libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js`, then the relative path would be `../libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js`.

Comment: ../../libs/moonlight-neon-ui/tailwind.config.js worked for me, thanks!